# ConstrainLayout Not scrolling inside NestedScrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make my layout scrollable with constrainlayout but it's not scrolling at all i also tried with scrollview and nestedscrollview also tried by making constrain root layout but still not getting scrollable layout. Here is my XML layout. Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    android:id="@+id/coverProfileImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:colorBackground">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coverPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:src="@color/custom_transparent_colorBlack"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/coverPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/coverPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.44"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addFriendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_only"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/profilePic"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profilePic"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_friend" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/messageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_only"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profilePic"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/coverPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityCountry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/coverPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/followerCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/followingCount"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/coverPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/followingCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/followerCount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/friendsCount"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/followerCount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/followerCount" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friendsCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/followingCount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/followingCount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/followingCount" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/followersTag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="460dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/followerCount"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/followerCount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/followingTag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/followersTag"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/followingCount"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/followingCount" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friendsTag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/followingTag"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/friendsCount"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/friendsCount" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/up_NestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            >
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabItemes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monday" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tuesday" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wednesday" />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/profileViewPager"
            android:layout_below="@id/tabItemes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" . try adding this attribute in nestedscrollview

Comment: @ChiragRayani Not working

Comment: @androidXP, Did I just see two nestedscrollview in same layout? Why? This would never scroll. Remove inner nestedscrollview and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CoordinatorLayout at the top of the nestedScrollView and set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` for NestedScrollView

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:measureAllChildren="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/home_constraint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why using 2 constrain layout. It's not performance optimized code

Comment: there is just 1 constraintLayout not 2

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add
android:isScrollContainer="true"
In your nestedScrollView